# How to return a char * from a Windows Thread function

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi

Hello this is somewhat of a multilayered question but basically I want my thread function to return a char *, and then I want to be able to access that result once the thread has terminated.

Currently I am type casting the char * to a DWORD at the end of my thread function like: (openPorts is my char *)

```
DWORD openPortsD = (DWORD)openPorts;
```

and then immediately returning openPortsD. But this does not seem to be working.

My thread creation logic looks like:

```
for (int j = 0; j < MAX_THREADS; j++)
{
  pDataArray[j] = (PMYDATA) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(MYDATA));

  if(pDataArray[j] == NULL)
  {
      ExitProcess(2);
  }
  pDataArray[j]->ip = ip;

  hThreadArray[j] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, connectPortW,  pDataArray[j], 0, &dwThreadIdArray[j]);

  if (hThreadArray[j] == NULL) 
  {
     ExitProcess(3);
  }
}
```

After I loop through my threads I then wait for my threads and then free/close them like:

```
WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);

for(int j = 0; j < MAX_THREADS; j++)
{
  CloseHandle(hThreadArray[j]);
  if(pDataArray[j] != NULL)
  {
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pDataArray[j]);
    pDataArray[j] = NULL;    // Ensure address is not reused.
  }
}
```

Now the second part would be how do I get the returned value. I understand I am supposed to use GetExitCodeThread() but I am unsure how to use it for multiple threads running. Moreover, since the return value will be a DWORD how do I get back my original string?

Comment: You're making life more difficult by using the thread exit code.  You can do it the same way as you do for the data (`pDataArray`, sized the same as the number of threads -- so make a `pResultArray` that the thread writes into instead of reading from)

Comment: exit code is `DWORD` - 4 byte, when pointer can be 8 bytes (in 64bit code). so already pointer not fit to exit code. you pass some object to thread - so thread and must strore return result in this object

Comment: If this is a GUI application the method to pass a string from a worker thread to the main thread is by allocating that string on the heap (operator `new` for C++ or `malloc` for C) and then by posting it in `WM_APP`-type message to the main thread (use `PostMessage` API.) Your main thread then in turn can process that message and free the string.

Comment: @ahmd0: This is *one* solution to the problem, and it doesn't require a GUI application. `new` and `malloc` are problematic, if the data crosses DLL boundaries. `HeapAlloc` is already better in this respect.

Comment: You are passing your threads pointers to a data structure (MYDATA). Why don't you just store the char*, as a char*, as a MYDATA member?

Comment: Instead of trying to return char* from the thread function, pass pre-allocated char * to the thread. And copy the result to it instead of allocating and returning the data. If allocation is not possible, you can also pass a pointer to a pointer variable (char**), and do the allocation inside the thread. Just make sure to use the same allocator/deallocated method pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already passing a structure to the thread, the best solution is to add a field to it for the thread to fill in.

```
typedef struct {
  const char *ip;
  const char *openports;
} MYDATA, *PMYDATA;

DWORD CALLBACK connectPortW(LPVOID ThreadParam)
{
  PMYDATA data = (PMYDATA) ThreadParam;
  data->openports = allocatestringandfillitwithlistofports(data->ip);
  return 0;
}

...

WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);
for(int j = 0; j < MAX_THREADS; j++)
{
  CloseHandle(hThreadArray[j]);
  if(pDataArray[j] != NULL)
  {
    parseandfreeports(pDataArray[j]);
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pDataArray[j]);
    pDataArray[j] = NULL;    // Ensure address is not reused.
  }
}
```

If this is a list of IP ports then it is better to store the ports in a array of SHORTs rather than a string.

As noted in the comments, you could allocate some memory and return it as the thread exit code in a 32-bit application but since a 64-it pointer does not fit in 4 bytes it would be impossible to port it to 64-bit.